# If statement not behaving correctly in while loop

Tags: python

So I'm working on a short program that finds the factors of a number. I have a while loop and an if statement within that loop that doesn't seem to execute.
Here's the code:

```
while e < a:
    print "loop"
    print str(e) + "e"
    print str(i) + "i"
    print str(a) + "a"
    if e * i == a:
        print e * i
        cFactors.append(e)
        cFactors.append(i)
        e += 1
        i = e
    else:
        print "adding i, " + str(i)
        i += 1
    if i > a:
        print "i > a"
        i = e
        e += 1
```

in this example, at the beginning of the loop `e = 1`, `i = 1`, and `a = 2`. The `if i > a:` is not executing. I've added debugging statements so I could find the issue but `i` clearly becomes more than `a`. Anyone have any idea what could be happening?

EDIT:
A lot of the answers are saying that the loop is not programmed correctly because it exits before it gets to the if statement because e becomes greater than a. Perhaps I phrased this wrong. It is infinitely looping when it should only loop a few times. Here is what happens when I run it, with debugging statements.

```
loop
1 = e
1 = i
2 = a
adding i, 1

loop
1 = e
2 = i
2 = a
adding i, 2

loop
1 = e
3 = i
2 = a
adding i, 3

loop
1 = e
4 = i
2 = a
adding i, 4
```

Sorry for any of the confusion but it's not that the loop is exiting before it gets to the statement. I did forget to mention that the if e * i == a: is not functioning properly earlier.

Comment: e = 1, i = 1, e*i = 1 a=2, else set i =2 a=2 so i is not > a

Comment: It would seem that I made a stupid mistake in which I forgot to convert a from a string to an integer on input.

Answer (score 2):

> "Core language feature X is not working correctly"

It does. If `e == 1`, `i == 1` and `a == 2`, then after the `i += 1` statement, `i == 2`. Now, `2 > 2` isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop exits before i > a, because i = e. Therefore the code within the if will not be executed.

Instead, try the following:

```
def factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant to mention that the if e*i == a: is not working either

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> **`i`** clearly becomes more than **`a`**

Yes, but not before `e` becomes equal to or greater than `a`. Breaking your loop.

Nothing is *wrong* with your code, you just didn't plan it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why should i>a execute? 2 is not greater than 2.so the if statement fails.